# How to modify Case assignment rule using apex code?

Tags: apex, case, assignment-rules

We have case assignment rule defined and we want to make process data driven. Is there a way we can modify case assignment rule with some apex coding?

Comment: I think you would be better off using an `Apex Trigger`. You can set the `OwnerId` based on data and be much more dynamic. Retooling actual `Assignment Rules` via `Apex` sounds horribly complicated.

Comment: I was waiting for a comment from @AdrianLarson thank you. We actually have everything in place, Utility class, wrapper and controller. I was wondering if we can use apex in any way to modify case assignment rules.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done

You only get control before assignment rules run in before/after triggers so, you need to do the following

**Option 1 (assumes you may want to keep some assignment rules)**

1. Create a new assignment rule that assigns to a queue called 'Pending Assignment Q'. Make it first in the sequence of rules
2. Create a custom Boolean field on Case called `is_custom_assignment__c`
3. Make the entry criteria for this assignment rule : `is_custom_assignment__c = true`
4. Create before insert trigger logic so that `is_pending_assignment__c` is set to true if the new Case requires custom assignment logic. If it does not, then do nothing. Assignment rules 2...n will execute per normal.
5. In before update trigger (which will be fired because the assignment rules will update the `Case.OwnerId`), see if case is owned by `Pending Assignment Q`. If yes, then apply your custom assignment logic.  If not, do nothing.

**Option 2 (assumes all assignment rules are custom)**

Simply don't use Case Assignment rules and let your before insert trigger do all custom assignment by setting `Case.OwnerId`

Comment: This sounds like a solution, so what I can do is keep the existing assignment  rule as is and do not touch them. But for new coming data if my conditions get fulfilled I can assign those cases using the before trigger. Problem here would be to accommodate this trigger with utility class that is already existing and creating a child case, grand child case and other logic.

Comment: the util class issue is something you'll have to deal with - doesn't really invalidate the above approach

Answer (score 4):

Assignment rules are metadata, and cannot be altered directly via Apex (cropredy's answer is a workable alternative).

As far as I know, they can only be altered via the Metadata API, which you also can't use directly via Apex.

You should be able to access the Metadata API by using [FinancialForce's Apex Metadata API Wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).

In the end, this is a horribly complex and convoluted way to go about things, and is likely to end in tears. I wouldn't recommend this approach to anyone. If cropredy's first solution doesn't work for you, a trigger is the appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will be trying to write a trigger.